# why is chrome and safari print out 'true' for Math.pow(2, -1075) === 0

Tags: javascript

from this article [How numbers are encoded in JavaScript](http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html),

> An exponent of 0 is used in two capacities. First, if the fraction is also 0 then the whole number is 0.

which seems indicate `Math.pow(2, -1023) === 0` should return `true`, but after test in chrome&safari they both print out '`true`' for `Math.pow(2, -1075)`, can someone help to explain why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point under the covers. Such numbers only have 11 bits devoted to exponent. Those 11 bits are used to encode a signed integer in 2's complement notation. Suffice it to say the -1075 is out of range. Here's a wikipedia excerpt for you:

> The exponent field can be interpreted as either an 11-bit signed
>   integer from −1024 to 1023 (2's complement) or an 11-bit unsigned
>   integer from 0 to 2047, which is the accepted biased form in the IEEE
>   754 binary64 definition. If the unsigned integer format is used, the
>   exponent value used in the arithmetic is the exponent shifted by a
>   bias – for the IEEE 754 binary64 case, an exponent value of 1023
>   represents the actual zero (i.e. for 2e − 1023 to be one, e must be
>   1023). Exponents range from −1022 to +1023 because exponents of −1023
>   (all 0s) and +1024 (all 1s) are reserved for special numbers. [[ref]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: what confusing me is according to the IEEE 754 specification, Math.pow(2, -1023) should be equal to 0, right?  
but those two browsers, prints 'true' for 'Math.pow(2, -1023) > 0', they only print out 0, when exponent field not more than -1075